# How to change all characters except for the two?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, regex-lookarounds

Let's suppose we have a string:

```
a = "I would like to go to dinner."
```

It is easy to change all `i`'s and `o`'s in the string to `-`'s. If we define:

```
b = re.sub("i|o","-", a, flags = re.I)
```

we get:

```
b = "- w-uld l-ke t- g- t- d-nner."
```

But I don't know how get:

```
"I -o--- -i-- -o -o -o -i-----"
```

in an elegant way using RE module (note that the last `-` in `b` is obtained by replacing dot). One could write

```
c = ""
for char in a:
    c += char if char.lower() in "io" else "-"
```

but I want to do this using RE. I tried to write something like

```
c =  re.sub('(?!i|o)', a, flags = re.I)
```

but that results in

```
"I- -wo-u-l-d- -li-k-e- -to- -go- -to- -di-n-n-e-r-.-"
```

and I don't know why. Obviously, I do not understand how `(?!...)` works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to specify a group of characters you *don't* want to match:

```
>>> re.sub("[^io ]", "-", a, flags=re.I)
'I -o--- -i-- -o -o -o -i-----'
```

Here, all characters except for `"i"`, `"o"` and `" "` are replaced by a hyphen (ignoring case). Placing characters inside a group prefixed with the `^` symbol means that those characters will be omitted from the matching.

Comment: No problem! `(?!...)` is negative lookahead, so `re.sub(r'(?!i|o)', '-', a)` would return the same string `a` but with a hyphen inserted after every letter that didn't immediately precede `i` or `o`.

Answer (score 1):

Lookarounds are zero length. For the replacement to work correctly, you need to match the character when the assertion in the negative lookahead is matched:

```
c = re.sub('(?!i|o).', a, flags = re.I)
```

Additionally, since whitespace characters doesn't have to be replaced, you can change `.` to `\S`:

```
c = re.sub('(?!i|o)\\S', a, flags = re.I)
```

Comment: Lookarounds are of length zero. That's it. Thank you.